# How to debug source code written in pytorch?

Tags: python, debugging, pytorch

This is a general question regarding how do you people debug pytorch source code? Via print statements? Any particular IDE-plugin combination?

I am a beginner and I think this question would help beginners like me.

Comment: I think this question is too general. Personally it's [`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

Comment: @Ivan.: I can guarantee you ..90% of the users don't use debugger. Only a handful few use them. So `pdb` is all there is? This question should be answered in much more ceremoniously I think. Why don't you put this as an answer?

Comment: All right, I'll write an answer down when I get time.